# HSQL database user lacks privilege or object not found error: PERSON, exception starts at the result set

Tags: java, hsqldb

I wrote a basic code for accessing a table in HQSQLDB.

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class FirstSQLAccess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:./database/firstSQLAccess/;shutdown=true;hsqldb.lock.file=false", "sa", "");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PERSON");

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + rs.getInt(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is it doesn't work as it should, as it gives this exception

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PERSON
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at FirstSQLAccess.main(FirstSQLAccess.java:24)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PERSON
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FirstSQLAccess.main(FirstSQLAccess.java:36)
```

This are the credentials in the data base menu:

[data base menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEBYt.png)

These are the files in my database folder:

[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AasWq.png)

I checked everything possible if the tablename is properly written, lowercase letters, a wrong URL, and so on, but I just can't find anything wrong with my code, as I have done it like this before and it shouldn't act up just like that.

Any help or criticism is appreciated

Comment: What i forgot to mention, the SQL-Statement is perfectly runnable, if I execute just this, it does it's job, so it knows where my table is, but ran as a code it just does nothing

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative path for the database. This results in multiple databases if you execute the Java command from different directories.

The other issues with your URL are the use of `hsqldb.lock.file=false` which should not be used if there is any chance of multiple process access to the database.

The third issue is use of empty string for the database name.

The URL can be `jdbc:hsqldb:file:./database/firstSQLAccess/db;shutdown=true`. You will get an error if you attempt to connect to the database while it is already open from another process.